# Hibernate Select on merge() seems useless

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, select, merge

I have a single table i am trying to understand the logic behind session.merge but i think is in somehow useless i will try to explain more with some code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final Merge clazz = new Merge();
    Ragonvalia ragonvalia = clazz.load();//LOADED FROM DATABASE...
    System.out.println("ORIGINAL: "+ragonvalia);  
    //Prints c02=1953
    clazz.session.evict(ragonvalia);//WE EVICT HERE FOR FORCE MERGE RELOAD FROM DB
    //HERE I MAKE SOME MODIFICATIONS TO THE RECORD IN THE DB DIRECTLY.....
    try{Thread.sleep(20000);}catch(final Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    //now c02=2000
    final Ragonvalia merge = ragonvalia = (Ragonvalia)clazz.session.merge(ragonvalia);//MERGE IN FACT THE SELECT IS THROWN
    System.out.println("MERGING");
    System.out.println("merge: "+merge);
    System.out.println("ragonvalia: "+ragonvalia);
    System.out.println(merge.toString().equals(ragonvalia.toString()));//PRINT EQUALS
    ragonvalia.setC01("PUEBLO LINDO");//I MODIFIY THE C01 FIELD
    System.out.println(ragonvalia);
    final Transaction tx = clazz.session.beginTransaction();
    clazz.session.update(merge);//WE UPDATE  
    tx.commit();    
    //In this point i can see the c02 was reset again to 1953    
    clazz.shutDown();        
}
```

Yep i know that merge is using for detached objects and all that stuff but what really are behind the select i just thought some things.

1. If when i retrieve the record from the first time thing the field c02=1953 latter was changed to c02=2000 i just though when the merge was made they would keep the new field already changed c02=2000 and if i do not modify the field in my session they would replace the c02 from 1953 which was the original to 2000 in the update to dont hurts anybody job when the keep the 1953 and updates the field as 1953 and 1953 replaces the 2000 in the database of course the job from the other person is lost.

I have read some stuff over the internet and i see something like this *Essentially, if you do not have a version or timestamp field, Hibernate must check the existing record before updating it so that concurrent modifications do not occur. You would not want a record updated that someone else modified after you read it. There are a couple of solutions, outlined in the link above. But it makes life much easier if can add a version field on each table.* Sounds great but *before updating it so that concurrent modifications do not occur* this is not happening Hibernate is just updating the fields i have in my class even when they are not the same in the currently DB record.

*Hibernate must check the existing record before updating* checking for what what hibernates checks?

In fact i am not using any version in my Models but seems the merge is only works to check that the records exists in the database.

I know this question is somehow simple or duplicate but i just cant see the logic or the benefits of firing a select.

Resume

After the merge Hibernate is updating all the properties even those whose unmodified i dont know why is this i just though that hibernate would update only the modified to gain performance, and the values of those properties are the same when the clazz was loaded for 1 time or modified by hand i think the merge was useless.

```
update
    ragonvalia 
set
    .....
    .....
    .....
    c01=?,
    c02=?,HERE IS 1953 EVEN WHEN THE MERGE WAS FIRED THE VALUE IN THE DB WAS 2000
    c03=? 
where
    ID=?
```

Comment: chiperortiz, did you get the answer to your question? I currently have exactly the same question.

Comment: Finally I guess it's because of the dirty checking. We don't need an UPDATE query at all if entity wasn't changed and SELECT is cheaper than UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mixes what appears to be 2 concerns.

#### Dynamic Update Statements

Hibernate has had support for `@DynamicUpdate` since 4.1.

> For updating, should this entity use dynamic sql generation where only changed
>   columns get referenced in the prepared sql statement.
>
> Note, for re-attachment of detached entities this is not possible without the
>   `@SelectBeforeUpdate` annotation being used.

This simply means that within the bounds of an open session, any entity attached to the session flagged with `@DynamicUpdate` will track field level changes and only issue DDL statements that include only the altered fields.

Should your entity be deattached from the session and you issue a merge, the `@SelectBeforeUpdate` annotation forces hibernate to refresh the entity from the database, attach it to the session and then determine dirty attributes in order to write the DDL statement with only altered fields.

It's worth pointing out that this will not guard you against concurrent updates to the same database records in a highly concurrent environment.  This is simply a means to minimize the DDL statement for legacy or wide tables where a majority of the columns aren't changed.

#### Concurrent Changes

In order to deal with concurrent operations on the same data, you can approach this using two types of locking mechanics.

**Pessimistic**

In this situation, you would want to apply a lock at read time which basically forces the database to prevent any other transaction from reading/altering that row until the lock is released.

Since this type of locking can have severe performance implications, particularly on a highly concurrent table, it's generally not preferred.  Most modern databases will reach a point of row level locks and eventually escalate them to the data page or worse the table; causing all other sessions to block until the locks are released.

```
 public void alterEntityWithLockExample() {
   // Read row, apply a row level update/write lock.
   Entity entity = entityManager.find(Entity.class, 1L, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
   // update entity and save it.
   entity.setField(someValue);
   entityManager.merge(entity);
 }
```

It is probably worth noting that had any other session queried the entity with id 1 prior to the write lock being applied in the code above, the two sessions would still step on one another.  All operations on `Entity` that would result in state changes would need to query using a lock in order to prevent concurrency issues.

**Opimistic**

This is a much more desired approach in a highly concurrent environment.  This is where you'd want to annotate a new field with `@Version` on your entity.

This has the benefit that you can query an entity, leave it detached, reattach it later, perhaps in another request or thread, alter it, and merge the changes.  If the record had changed since it was originally fetched at the start of your process, an `OptimisticLockException` will be thrown, allowing your business case to handle that scenario however you need.

In a web application as an example, you may want to inform the user to requery the page, make their changes, and resave the form to continue.

*Pessimisitic locking is a proactive locking mechanic where-as optimistic is more reactionary*.